# How to fix the CocoaPods issue when running a Flutter project on an iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart, cocoapods

I have updated to the last version of `CocoaPods`, but still, it's not working. I have deleted previous versions before updating to the newest, but nothing changed. When I run the `main.dart` code on an iOS simulator, here's the output.

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

```
Ignoring ffi-1.15.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5
\[!\] The version of CocoaPods used to generate the lockfile (1.12.1) is higher than the version of the current executable (1.11.3). Incompatibility issues may arise.

Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
pod repo update

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.
```

---

When I run pod update, I get :

```
\[!\] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Storage":
In Podfile:
firebase_storage (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_storage/ios`) was resolved to 11.2.2, which depends on
Firebase/Storage (= 10.12.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Storage (= 10.12.0)`.

You have either:

* mistyped the name or version.
* not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

Comment: It looks like it's recommending that you run pod repo update, not pod update, the error is that your repos are out of date, so it can't find the compatible version.